# How to get seaborn banded line plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Okay so first of all, I am not so sure whether it is the correct terminology to call the dim colored error bands around a sns.lineplot() banded error style but the main question is when I am watching tutorial on the internet, I am seeing people plotting with seaborn get a cool and nice looking figure with confidence intervals around it. for example see the image below:

[image: plot]

but In my case the lineplots are simply plotted as if it were plotted with the standard matplotlib, meaning no bands etc.

How to fix it

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (8,8))
sns.lineplot(data = volcano, y="SO2", x = volcano.index)
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get regions of error around your plot, your dataset must consist of more than one dataset. From this multitude of datasets, the confidence interval is estimated. To configure the appearance of the error region further, use the [`error_bar`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/error_bars.html) argument.

In your case, you combine the "S02" volcano dataset with the monotoneously rising index, which leaves only a single dataset, and hence no "room for error".

Here's an example with a dataset consisting of multiple datasets:
[image]

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset("diamonds")
sns.lineplot(df, x="carat", y="price")
plt.show()
```

The chosen "carat vs price" plot has multiple variations (e.g. "clarity", "cut", ...) and hence multiple datasets, from which a confidence interval can be estimated. For carat > 3, only single dataset are present, and hence the confidence interval vanishes.